# I can't enter UEFI Firmware Settings on my old Windows 10 PC

Tags: bios

I want to upgrade my current SSD to a larger one so I must modify my boot order in my BIOS. The PC is the ASUS ROG GR8 II and its motherboard is split into several pieces to make it more compact. However, I'm not able to enter my BIOS no matter what I do. I've already tried:

- Spamming F2 or DEL when I start my PC
- Booting to BIOS using advanced startup
- Resetting my CMOS battery
- Reinstalling windows

I got this PC around 5 years ago and I remember that I was able to enter the BIOS until some time ago.

Comment: Start the machine so it is running.  Then Restart it.  At the beginning of the restart press the BIOS access Key (often F1).  See if there is a message on screen to press Enter to get into setup. Restart slows the process down.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the windows hard disk out.